# Ajax response with newlines for textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem concerning an ajax-request that should return a string from the server with newlines (\n) to fill the textarea.

When I do the following just with javascript, it works and shows 2 lines in the textarea:

```
function fillTextArea(){
document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = "Line1\nLine2";
}
```

But if I get the value from the server using ajax, the \n is treated like all the other characters of the String and there's just one line

```
function fillTextArea() {
new Ajax.Request("/myUrl/....",{
    asynchronous:true,
    evalScripts:true,
    onSuccess:function(transport){
        document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = transport.responseText;
    }
});
}
```

Does anybody know how to deal with newlines in the responseText of an ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.innerHTML = "Line1\nLine2"`.  Use `.value = "Line1\nLine2"` instead.

`value` is for form values. You are not setting HTML contents here.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. But it doesn't change the problem i have, still the same difference between the 2 functions.

Comment: @sergej: If you do not get newlines from the Ajax function, then there are no newlines in `transport.responseText`, it's as easy as that. The text area does not care whether its value is being set within an XHR callback function or elsewhere. Please check that the Ajax response is sent as `text/plain` and *actually contains* `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

@Tomalak: The Ajax Function returns a String with the \n like "Line1\nLine2", but the textarea just shows one row with the whole String, so \n is just also shown in the textarea as text instead of making a new line.

I've found a small workaround:

If my ajax function returns "Line1NEWLINELine2" and it replaces "NEWLINE" with \n, this works, so the function looks like that:

```
function fillTextArea() {
new Ajax.Request("/myUrl/....",{
    asynchronous:true,
    evalScripts:true,
    onSuccess:function(transport){
        var responseText = transport.responseText;
        var adjustedResponseText = responseText.replace(/NEWLINE/g, '\n');

        document.getElementById('myTextArea').value= adjustedResponseText;
    }
});
}
```

I am really not sure, why it makes a difference, if the value comes from a ajax request or just as a static string in the javascript function. But this is a way to solve that.

Any better suggestions are welcome :-)